# Adding python projects with pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Ubuntu 16 and python 3.5.2
Trying to add some python scripts in a folder /opt/python_scripts
Tons of SSL errors on any pip install so I upgraded pip to 19.2.1 
The only way I could upgrade it was with

```
sudo python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip
```

didn't help still got SSL errors but at least seems to work anyway

I want to try and get in the habit of using python environments to isolate requirements etc. 
Following pipenv instructions...
I made a python_scripts folder under opt and installed pipenv

```
/opt/python_scripts$ pip3 install pipenv
```

but

```
/opt/python_scripts$ pipenv shell
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pipfile'
/opt/python_scripts$ sudo pipenv shell
sudo: pipenv: command not found
```

Assuming the correct thing to do is to add my scripts under the opt folder.
How can I get pipenv to work under that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first make sure pyhon is correct installed do the following `python3 -V` assuming that it's properly installed you get the correct version no error's or warnings do this `sudo apt install python3-pip` once installed verify `pip3 list` if you have errors do the following `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper` You will have to add the command to `source`/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh to your shell startup so do the following

```
nano .bashrc

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

now run this command `source ~/.bashrc` I hope now your up and running, if you real need to use the `pipenv` then do the following `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` then run this to verify `pipenv shell`

Good lucky and happy coding.

Comment: Cool, thank you!  I get the feeling I'm making it way more complicated by using pipenv.  I'm just going to remove it and start over - thank you!

Comment: You could try venv to create a virtual environment, it is faster to create.